# How to synchronize a GIT repository with SVN?

Tags: svn, git, repository

I am planning to make a fork of an open-source project, but I want to switch to GIT. The project is using SVN, but there is no TRAC available, so I can't just download changesets without having SVN on my PC (not to mention svn diff doesn't allow binary patches).

Is there a way to synchronize my GIT master repository with SVN's HEAD/trunk without keeping another project on my HDD?

Answer (score 4):

You can synchronize SVN with Git using [git-svn(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn).

If you have existing Git repository, and want to bind with another SVN repository, you can try some kind of voodoo, see http://blog.experimentalworks.net/2009/07/git-voodoo/.

The blog shows how to convert existing non-git-svn Git repository, to git-svn-enabled Git repository with a new created remote SVN repository. You can modify the voodoo workflow a little to import an existing SVN repository to you Git repository:

1. Import the trunk as a parallel branch into your existing Git repository

   ```
   cd GIT-REPO
   git svn clone --stdlayout SVN-URL .
   ```
2. Setup the graft:

   ```
   TRUNK_HEAD=`git rev-parse trunk`
   MASTER_INIT=`git rev-list --reverse master | head -1`
   echo $MASTER_INIT $TRUNK_HEAD >.git/info/grafts
   ```
3. Find out the range in master branch to be appended to trunk, for example, only the changes start from tag v2.0 will be appended to trunk.
4. Rebase trunk

   ```
   git checkout master
   git rebase --onto trunk v2.0 master
   ```
5. Commit to trunk

   ```
   git svn dcommit
   ```

A usage hint: by using grafts with git-svn, you should ensure you won't `dcommit` empty commits. Otherwise, `dcommit` will fail. To filter away the empty commits, try

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty
```

before the first time `dcommit`.

Comment: I need to do the opposite - sync GIT with SVN. I will be committing to a GIT repository.

Comment: You can do it, too. I have modified my answer to reflect it.

Comment: As far as I read, dcommit is for svn commits, but I won't be committing to the svn.  BTW, I will be using EGit for Eclipse, not the console client.

Comment: Oh. You won't commit to the remote SVN, yes? Then, after `git svn clone` to your local Git repository, you can treat it just as normal Git repository. You will do nothing to dcommit.

Comment: So you should mention EGit in your question. I'm using EGit, too, to get the filename status icon work. but I mostly doing git work outside of eclipse. Unfortunately, I didn't find useful git-svn function in EGit, yet. Maybe you should write your own extension.

Comment: Well, that's the thing, I will be committing only to my GIT repo, but I want to do with the master the same as Team>Synchronize with Repository. I know it's probably impossible because afaik synchronization checks .svn files/folders which GIT won't have, but IMHO something like that that compares the code between GIT and SVN repos would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an access to your SVN repository you may install [SubGit](http://subgit.com) into it.
Just run

```
$ subgit install path/to/your/svn/repostiory
```

All the synchronization will be performed automatically (triggered by SVN and Git hooks).
In this case not only master/trunk but all the branches will be in sync (though you can configure its behaviour).

**Disclaimer**: I'm one of the developers of this product.