# Deploying Java web application to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, git-svn, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My team is developing a Java web application which is to be deployed in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. The development environment is Eclipse and Subversion. They were able to deploy it using the Eclipse plugin, but to automate the deployment I'm experimenting with the CLI tools provided by Amazon.

Basically, I followed the steps detailed in the [Amazon Blog post](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/aws-elastic-beanstalk-simplfied-command-line-eb.html) after converting the subversion repository into a git repository. I followed the steps explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368643/how-to-synchronize-a-git-repository-with-svn)

After following the above steps, I issued the command git **aws.push**, which is successfully completed. But while running the application, there are errors and . So I downloaded the war file from the Beanstalk environment and found that the folder structure is messed up and the source files are not compiled to class files. It appears like the source files are uploaded as such.

Do I need to build the application(using ant) prior to using aws.push? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why not directy deploy the war file with `upload and deploy` on elastic beanstalk ?

Comment: At that time I needed an incremental deployment feature and using aws.push is really quick

Comment: @DeepakMishra do you have more info as to how to do the upload and deploy of a war file via the CLI?  We are building our war files and want to push those, instead of pushing from Git.

Answer (score 6):

It seems now I have the answer for my question.

**aws.push** is not only for PHP applications, instead it can also be used for deploying Java and PHP applications. I have successfully used along with **Apache Ant** and the setup works fine in our UAT environment.

I developed a shell script which does the following:

1. Check out the source code from subversion repository
2. Build and created WAR file using Apache Ant
3. Explode the WAR file to a git repository (initialised using Amazon
   EB tools)
4. Add the exploded files to the git repo and commit the changes.
5. Use aws.push to deploy the war file to EB.

*(I don't have access to the shell script right now, so I may not be able to provide the detailed commands)*

**Here is the Shell Script in the basic form**

```
source_dir="/home/libregeek/myapp"
workingcopy="$source_dir/trunk"
gitrepo="$source_dir/gitrepo"
cd $workingcopy
svn update
ant createwar
cd $gitrepo
unzip -o $workingcopy/build/myapp.war
git add *
git commit -m "Deployed new version"
git aws.push
```

There is a known issue with this script related to stale class files. To get away with it you may have to clean up the git repo.

Here is the ant target:

```
<target name="createwar" depends="build" description="Create WAR file for deployment">
<war destfile="${alternate.path}/${name}.war" webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
<fileset dir="${web.dir}">
<include name="**/*.*"/>
</fileset>
</war>
</target>
```

Comment: When do you this, does Elastic Beanstalk still bundle up the exploded WAR so you can go back and forth between versions?

Comment: Yes, you can switch between the versions.

Comment: @AaronGreenlee I'm happy to share the script, but I was too busy. Will try soon.

Answer (score 1):

It you're using Maven and [Beanstalker](http://docs.ingenieux.com.br/project/beanstalker/), the equivalent functionality of git aws.push could be resumed to a single command, regardless if you're using git or not.

`$ mvn package beanstalk:fast-deploy`

but make sure your [pom is ready](http://docs.ingenieux.com.br/project/beanstalker/deploying-using-git.html)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem - it appears the git method is only designed to work with PHP apps.

I'm currently looking for some other Java-based tool, as I don't use Eclipse, and the AWS console is a clunky way of managing releases (and the uploads are very slow).

Comment: Further questions are not asked in answers , comments can be added to clarfy / ask things.

Comment: The -SNAPSHOT builds of maven-beanstalk-plugin include experimental support for git-based deployment from maven-based projects