# Automated synchronization Git repository with SVN in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a temporary solution to to push new updates to our git repository from SVN via a local machine but this is manually done and we also tried it using [git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368643/how-to-synchronize-a-git-repository-with-svn). 
The manual process is as follows:

1. Create a local directory for SVN development repo
2. clone existing SVN project repo into local directory
3. Initialize local directory using git
4. push this project into our Gitlab
5. every time there is a new update from SVN we just update our local copy with SVN
6. Using git we push this updates to Gitlab manually

However we'd like to automate this process if its possible using gitlab mirroring but we only see examples where it mirrors a git and another git repo. 
Another way is probably using Gitlab jobs/runner but we are not sure if it can do what we want.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be achieved using repository mirroring. All you need to do is initialize the repository as a git repository and it should work fine.
The only condition is the repository should be accessible.
You can set up a repository to automatically have its branches, tags, and commits updated from an upstream repository. This is useful when a repository you're interested in is located on a different server. You can find more info [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/workflow/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository)

The other option can be using an svn webhook that triggers the remote repository mirroring as mentioned [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#start-the-pull-mirroring-process-for-a-project)